# How to update a child component when incrementing it in the parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**The problem**: Whenever I increment the input field provided by the child component, the value doesn't set back to zero. It assumes the value of the previous instance.

**Note**: The increment is **implemented in parent component method**

### Child component

```js
<input type="number" placeholder="Amount" :value="value"  @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value/>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

### Parent Component

```js
<template>
   <div>

<form-input v-for="n in count" :key="n" v-model="expense"> </form-input>

   <button @click="addInputs">Add Expense</button>

   <button @click="deleteInputs">Delete</button>


   </div>
</template>

export default {
  components: {
    "form-input": formInput
  },
  name: "form",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      earnings: "",
      expense: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addInputs: function() {
      this.count++;

    },
    deleteInputs: function() {
      this.count--;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Please feel free to ask any questions if there any more needed information

Comment: What is strange about it ? You are rendering multiple `form-input` components but each and every one is using single field `expense` in your parent component to store the value....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you passing a value prop from the parent anyway? Shouldn't the value of the child be self-controlled?

Try removing the binding of value.

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Amount" @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value/>`
```

Comment: That's not the problem. Using `v-model="expense"` on custom component is same as `v-bind:value="expense" v-on:input="expense = $event"`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: Right, so you are passing `expenses` as the value for every input element... That is why they are the same.

Comment: I was under the assumption that v-model was synonymous to        :value="value"  @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value) but I see that the value was not needed. Thanks